# How can I get this document.body.appendChild image in a div class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is a `contenteditable="true"` DIV. When we paste any image in this div then it appends into `document.body.appendChild` with `blob` URL.

And then the HTML structure become like this:

```
<img src="blob:https://www.some.com/0606f154-ce49-4048-9321-27778280b2d3">
<img src="blob:https://www.some.com/0606f154-ce49-4048-9321-27778280b2d3">
```

But I want this image appended, `document.body.appendChild(image);`, into a div class when it gets appended.

Like this:

```
<div class="someclass"><img src="blob:https://www.some.com/0606f154-ce49-4048-9321-27778280b2d3"></div>
<div class="someclass"><img src="blob:https://www.some.com/0606f154-ce49-4048-9321-27778280b2d3"></div>
```

I tried these many things, but it didn't work:

```
document.body.appendChild(`<div class="someclass">` + image + '</div> );
```

**My Whole Code is:**

```js
var PasteImage = function (el) {
  this._el = el;
  this._listenForPaste();
};

PasteImage.prototype._getImageFromContentEditableOnNextTick = function () {
  var self = this;

  // We need to wait until the next tick as Firefox will not have added the image to our
  // contenteditable element
  setTimeout(function () {
self._getImageFromContentEditable();
  });
};

PasteImage.prototype._getURLObj = function () {
  return window.URL || window.webkitURL;
};

PasteImage.prototype._pasteImage = function (image) {
  this.emit('paste-image', image);
};

PasteImage.prototype._pasteImageSource = function (src) {
  var self = this,
image = new Image();

  image.onload = function () {
self._pasteImage(image);
  };

  image.src = src;
};


PasteImage.prototype._onPaste = function (e) {

  // We need to check if event.clipboardData is supported (Chrome & IE)
  if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.items) {

// Get the items from the clipboard
var items = e.clipboardData.items;

// Loop through all items, looking for any kind of image
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i].type.indexOf('image') !== -1) {
    // We need to represent the image as a file
    var blob = items[i].getAsFile();

    // Use a URL or webkitURL (whichever is available to the browser) to create a
    // temporary URL to the object
    var URLObj = this._getURLObj();
    var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);

    // The URL can then be used as the source of an image
    this._pasteImageSource(source);

    // Prevent the image (or URL) from being pasted into the contenteditable element
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
  }
  else {
// If we can't handle clipboard data directly (Firefox & Safari), we need to read what was
// pasted from the contenteditable element
this._getImageFromContentEditableOnNextTick();
  }
};

PasteImage.prototype._listenForPaste = function () {
  var self = this;

  self._origOnPaste = self._el.onpaste;

  self._el.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {

self._onPaste(e);

// Preserve an existing onpaste event handler
if (self._origOnPaste) {
  self._origOnPaste.apply(this, arguments);
}
  });
};

// TODO: use EventEmitter instead
PasteImage.prototype.on = function (event, callback) {
  this._callback = callback;
};

// TODO: use EventEmitter instead
PasteImage.prototype.emit = function (event, arg) {
  this._callback(arg);
};

PasteImage.prototype._loadImage = function (src) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
  resolve(img);
};
img.src = src;
  });
};

PasteImage.prototype._findFirstImage = function () {
  var self = this;

  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
for (var i in self._el.childNodes) {
  var node = self._el.childNodes[i];

  // Is the element an image?
  if (node.tagName === 'IMG') {

    resolve(node);

  } else if (node.childNodes[0]) { // Are there children?

    // If you copy an image from within Safari and then paste it within Safari, the image can be
    // nested somewhere under the contenteditable element.
    var imgs = node.getElementsByTagName('img');

    if (imgs) {
      resolve(imgs[0]);
    }
  }
}

// No image found so just resolve
resolve();
  });
};

PasteImage.prototype._removeFirstImage = function () {
  var self = this;

  return self._findFirstImage().then(function (img) {
if (img) {
  // In Safari if we copy and image and then paste an image within Safari we need to construct a
  // proper image from the blob as Safari doesn't do this for us. Moreover, we need to wait for
  // our converted image to be loaded before removing the image from the DOM as otherwise there
  // can be a race condition where we remove the image before it has been loaded and this
  // apparently stops the loading process.
  return self._loadImage(img.src).then(function (loadedImage) {
    img.parentElement.removeChild(img);

    return loadedImage;
  });
}
  });
};

PasteImage.prototype._getImageFromContentEditable = function () {
  var self = this;

  this._removeFirstImage().then(function (img) {
// Process the pasted image
self._pasteImage(img);
  });
};

// -----

var pasteImage = new PasteImage(document.getElementById('my-div'));

pasteImage.on('paste-image', function (image) {
document.body.appendChild( image );
});
```

```html
<title>Paste Image Example</title>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.4.6/bluebird.min.js"></script>


<h1>
Copy an image and then press Command+V (Mac) or Ctrl+V (Windows) anywhere in the div below.
</h1>

<div id="my-div" contenteditable="true"
style="border:1px solid #777777;height: 50px;padding: 5px;"
onpaste="console.log('onpastefromhtml')">
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `appendChild(node)` expects you to pass the reference to an element (node), not a string. The DOM API is not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear, here is what you will need to do:

Just replace this:

```
var pasteImage = new PasteImage(document.getElementById('my-div'));

pasteImage.on('paste-image', function (image) {
    document.body.appendChild( image );
});
```

With this:

```
var pasteImage = new PasteImage(document.getElementById('my-div'));

pasteImage.on('paste-image', function (image) {
   // Create a new div element to put your image in:
   var newDivElement = document.createElement("div");

   // Add the image element to the div:
   newDivElement.append(image);

   // Append the div

   document.body.append(newDivElement);
});
```